# Is it possible to store an ElasticSearch scripted metric with line breaks and comments?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am aware that I can save files to the `config/scripts` directory on my ES nodes:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html

If I do that, I can obviously include line-breaks and comments in those files.

However, in my current environment, it is not feasible to do it that way.

Is it possible to maintain line-breaks inside a query?

I have tried replacing line breaks with "\n" to no avail:

```
...
"my_scripted_field": {
  "scripted_metric": {
    "map_script": "_agg['foo'] = 'bar'\n_agg['test'] = 'blah'\n"
  }
},
...
```

If not, what is the best-practice way to maintain code for scripted queries?

Essentially, I am writing the scripts in a text editor and I would like be able to preserve the formatting and add comments, so that the code is maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An advice from the [documentation itself](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html):

> JSON cannot include embedded newline characters. Newline characters in the script should either be escaped as `\n` or replaced with semicolons.